# "Permission denied" trying to get a file using TFTP

Tags: fedora, tftp

I started `tftp-server`, but I'm confused by this error:

```
nisemono ncdy # chmod 777 /tftproot/test 
mode of `/tftproot/test' changed to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
nisemono ncdy # tftp 192.168.0.2        
tftp> get test
Error code 0: Permission denied
```

0 bytes file is copied... But for what Permission denied??? I don't like the message.

```
cat /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
service tftp
{
    disable = no
    socket_type     = dgram
    protocol        = udp
    wait            = yes
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args     = -s /tftproot
    per_source      = 11
    cps             = 100 2
    flags           = IPv4
}
```

Why is this failing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Insufficient data for meaningful analysis.  How are you invoking the tftp server?  Show us the inetd or xinetd entry.  Show us the mode bits of the /tftproot directory.

Comment: Might want to add which tftp server you're using, and its configuration file.

Comment: everything is qual this tutorial http://llbb.wordpress.com/2007/06/14/installing-tftp-on-fedora/

Comment: tftpserver usually write some explain to the log files - try it search for the complain of tftp server by `cd /var/log ; grep tftp *`. In my opinion you will nedd to change permission only to 644.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably a selinux problem. Do a `ls -alZ` in the directory. On RHEL5/Centos5 the context should be `user_u:object_r:tftpdir_t`.

You can run `restorecon -Rv /tftproot` to fix it.

**Edit:**
Just saw the fedora tag. It seems you're using not F16 but an earlier version, so the instructions above should work for you. With F16 the tftproot is in /var/lib and the context is `system_u:object_r:tftpdir_rw_t:s0`.

Comment: I'm using F16. but restorecon doesn't help me. (even when I switched to /var/lib/tftpboot)

Comment: Seems like it fixed now ) not sure how exactly but in final I set 666 mod.

Comment: You can test if this is the problem with `setenforce 0` to switch selinux temporarily off.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to save the file into a directory where you have no write permissions? Were you in `/etc` when you called `tftp hostaddr`?

Answer (score -2):

That is the problem with setenforce. Type the command as setenforce 0 as SUDO.
This resolves the issue.

Comment: Turning off selinux is never the right answer in the long term, you can use this to check whether selinux is stopping you from doing something as a quick test before turning it back on and fixing the selinux context. But turning off selinux is simply a dumb idea